# Compare two arrays and make the another array with difference in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the below type of two arrays, I want to check both array(`array1` and `array2`) and create another array(`array3`), which has a value, which are not available into `array1`.

For ex - `'mob2', 'pin', 'address2', 'city'` are available in `array1` but not in `array2`. I want to those array keys and values in `array3`.

```js
let array3 = [];
let array1 = {
    'fname': 'test text',
    'lname': 'test text',
    'pin': 856,
    'address1': 'test text',
    'address2':'test text',
    'city': 'test text',
    'mob1': 35343434343,
    'mob2': 34343434343
};
let array2 = ['fname','lname','mob1','address1'];
```

**Expected Output**:

```js
array3['mob2'] = 34343434343;
array3['pin'] = 856;
array3['address2'] = 'test text';
array3['city'] = 'test text';
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using an array instead of an object literal for `arr1`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: `array1` and `array3` should be objects.

Comment: can i achieve using array or I have to use objects only?

Comment: you _can_ use an array of array3 and array1, but it doesn't really make sense to do so. Array 2 is fine as an array

Comment: Your objects/arrays would make more sense/make your question clearer if you formatted it like so https://jsfiddle.net/6a14tLrn/ (imo at least)

Comment: can u give me solution for object, i will be use object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first get all the [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) from your first object into an array

```
['fname', 'lname', 'pin', ...] // keys from `obj`
```

You can then use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on this array to remove any key values that appear in your `arr` of keys to exclude. This will give you an array of keys to keep, which you can map over to create an array of `[key, value]` pairs. This key-value pair array can then be used in a call to [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), which will build your resulting object for you:

```js
const obj = {
  'fname': 'test text',
  'lname': 'test text',
  'pin': 856,
  'address1': 'test text',
  'address2':'test text',
  'city': 'test text',
  'mob1': 35343434343,
  'mob2': 34343434343
};
const arr = ['fname', 'lname', 'mob1', 'address1']; // keys to exclude

const keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => !arr.includes(key));
const res = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(key => [key, obj[key]]));
console.log(res);
```

If the number of keys to exclude is large, consider making a Set first, and then using `.has()` instead of `.includes()`. This will allow for efficient lookup within your `.filter()` callback:

```js
const obj = {
  'fname': 'test text',
  'lname': 'test text',
  'pin': 856,
  'address1': 'test text',
  'address2':'test text',
  'city': 'test text',
  'mob1': 35343434343,
  'mob2': 34343434343
};
const set = new Set(['fname', 'lname', 'mob1', 'address1']); // keys to exclude

const keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => !set.has(key));
const res = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(key => [key, obj[key]]));
console.log(res);
```

Lastly, if the keys in `array2` are static, you use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to pull out the keys you want to exclude, and then use the rest pattern `...` to obtain an object without those keys. This only works with static keys though:

```js
const obj = { 'fname': 'test text', 'lname': 'test text', 'pin': 856, 'address1': 'test text', 'address2':'test text', 'city': 'test text', 'mob1': 35343434343, 'mob2': 34343434343 };

const {fname, lname, mob1, address1, ...res} = obj;
console.log(res);
```